# Find data between dates in two tables Hiveql

Tags: hiveql

I have the following two tables:

1. Member Download Details
2. Member Dimensions.

From the member dimensions table, I would like to pull out details for a member based on certain download end dates.

**Member Download Details Table (Table name: MDD)**
[image: Member Download Table]

**Member Dimensions Table (Table name: MD)**

[image: Member Dimensions Table]

I would like to bring back the "Status" for a member when their download date is between the start and end date. I know this can be achieve with a BETWEEN in hiveql (for Member 2) **BUT** the tricky part is for Member 1, the download date falls between both the rows in member dimensions. In this case the latest row with 999-000 is what should be returned. Also if there are members in the Download table that are not in the Dimensions table, they should also be returned with NULL.

The output table should be like

[image: Output Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
(select member_no,download_date,startdate,enddate,status,
row_number() over(partition by member_no order by enddate desc) rownum 
from member_download_details as dd 
     left join member_dimensions md 
on(dd.member_no=md.member_no and download_date between startdate and enddate)
) 
where rownum=1;
```

by using `row_number` we can easily get the desired result try above one once.